# Pasting mask over an image

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have an original image from which I extracted the mask after drawing contours and some other processing. The original image and the mask are shown below:

[image: original image]

The corresponding mask(relevant to my case) is this:

[image: mask]

Now when I try to merge both the images, I got weird results. I tried to merge the images as `final_image = (mask==255)*original_image`

But the output of the above code is this:

[image: result]

Can someone please help me find out why is this happening?

Comment: final_image = (mask==255)*original_image+mask might work. Also mask==255 need not necessarily be the outside mask region. The red marks might be the 255 values of the face in the mask

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Your *mask* is not a *binary mask* but actually a *masked image*. Most of the time when people reference a mask they mean a binary mask with only 255 and 0 (or 1 and 0 or True and False or whatever binary recognition). What output are you actually expecting, because your posted *mask* looks exactly like what someone would be trying to achieve with masking. What's happening in your code is all the pixels at 255 are being set to the original image, and all the pixels otherwise are being set to 0. Inspect the output of `mask==255`.

Comment: your mask is not a 1 channel image,  so it checks value with 255 in each channel, you may end with some red or blue or green with 255 as well. Also I think you should use `cv2.bitwise_and(original_image,original_image,mask = mask)` once you have binary mask, since 1 channel * 3 channels will give you another error. Also, in a mask the true values or 1 or 255 are the ones to be copied, so in your case you copy the background as the white is 255 in all channels, and you copy where the red channel was 255 inside the face